# Boot receiver doesn't work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to implement a broadcast receiver that catch the boot complete event.

I put the permission in the manifet

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

I put the intent filter after the receiver tag in the manifest (the class file is in the receivers package)

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.BootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and finally I declared the receiver class. The class should load some data from the database and set an alarm. However to check if it works I've put a Toast but it's not displayed and a vibra.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent callingIntent) {
       Vibrator vibrator=(Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
       vibrator.vibrate(5000);
       Toast.makeText(context, "BOOT RECEIVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

Anyone knows why please?

Answer (score 1):

All just installed applications gets into the stopped state (the actual file is /data/system/packages-stopped.xml)

Starting from Android 3.1, the system's package manager keeps track of applications that are in a stopped state. See this link: [android 3.1 launch control](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols).

Intent with action `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` has a `FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` extra flag. It means that all stopped applications will not receive the `BOOT_COMPLETED` events.

To get your application out of the stopped state, start it manually just after installation. Then you can do a reboot and will see the expected Toast.

Comment: +1 for the interesting explanation - I was just going to answer by saying you need to run the app first before it will receive it. Nice.

Comment: Thanks. BTW preinstalled application doesn't go to the /data/system/packages-stopped.xml , and thus all of them are able to receive the event.  Additionally, force-stop of the application make this application to go into this file, meaning to the stopped state.